# Expand values of a column to n rows before and m rows after after the value in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data-manipulation

I have a `data.frame` representing different time series. In one column, I marked interesting time points (Note: There can be multiple interesting time points per Id):

| Id | Time | Value | Interesting |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 12 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 14 | 0 |
| 1 | 2 | 11 | 0 |
| 1 | 3 | 12 | 1 |
| 1 | 4 | 13 | 0 |
| 1 | 5 | 14 | 0 |
| 1 | 6 | 12 | 0 |
| 1 | 7 | 12 | 0 |
| .. | .. | .. | .. |
| 78 | 128 | 13 |  |

Now, I would like to mark also `n` time points before and `m` points afterward as an interesting block. So if `n = 2` and `m = 3` I would expect this:

| Id | Time | Value | Interesting | Block |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 12 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 14 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 11 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 3 | 12 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 4 | 13 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 5 | 14 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 6 | 12 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 7 | 12 | 0 | 0 |
| .. | .. | .. | .. | .. |
| 78 | 128 | 13 | 0 | 0 |

At the moment, I use a `gaussianSmooth()` and a threshold:

```
df %>% mutate(Block = ifelse(gaussianSmooth(Interesting, sigma = 4) > 0.001, 1, 0))
```

But this is cumbersome works and only works if `n = m`. Is there a “simpler” solution where I can easily set how many rows before and after should be changed. Solutions preferable in `dplyr`/`tidyverse`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `group_modify` (works for multiple `Interesting` values too). Get the indices you like: here the position when `Interesting == 1`, and then iteratively replace surrounding values with `1` (`max(0, i - n):min(nrow(.x), i + m)`).

```r
library(dplyr)
n = 2
m = 3

df %>% 
  group_by(Id) %>% 
  group_modify(~ {
    idx <- which(.x$Interesting == 1)
    for(i in idx){
      .x$Interesting[max(0, i - n):min(nrow(.x), i + m)] <- 1
    }
    .x
  })

# A tibble: 8 × 4
# Groups:   Id [1]
     Id  Time Value Interesting
  <int> <int> <int>       <dbl>
1     1     0    12           0
2     1     1    14           1
3     1     2    11           1
4     1     3    12           1
5     1     4    13           1
6     1     5    14           1
7     1     6    12           1
8     1     7    12           0
```

Answer (score 1):

I would create a custom function `before_and_after()` which creates dummy variables and then takes the `rowSums`.

Below I use `dplyover::over()` for the dummy variables (disclaimer: I'm the maintainer), but you can also use other packages.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(dplyover)

before_and_after <- function(x, bef, aft) {
  tbl <- tibble(x = x)
  tbl <- mutate(tbl,
                over(seq_len(bef),
                     ~ lead(x, n = .x, default = 0),
                     .names = "bef_{x}"
                     ),
                over(seq_len(aft),
                     ~ lag(x, n = .x, default = 0),
                     .names = "aft_{x}"
                )
                )
  rowSums(tbl)
}

dat %>%   
  mutate(Block = before_and_after(Interesting,
                                  bef = 1,
                                  aft = 2),
         .by = Id)

#> # A tibble: 8 x 5
#>      Id  Time Value Interesting Block
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     0    12           0     0
#> 2     1     1    14           0     0
#> 3     1     2    11           0     1
#> 4     1     3    12           1     1
#> 5     1     4    13           0     1
#> 6     1     5    14           0     1
#> 7     1     6    12           0     0
#> 8     1     7    12           0     0
```

Data from OP

```r
dat <- tribble(~Id, ~ Time, ~Value, ~Interesting, 
   1   , 0    ,12    , 0           ,
   1   , 1    ,14    , 0           ,
   1   , 2    ,11    , 0           ,
   1   , 3    ,12    , 1           ,
   1   , 4    ,13    , 0           ,
   1   , 5    ,14    , 0           ,
   1   , 6    ,12    , 0           ,
   1   , 7    ,12    , 0
   )
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

We can first set `row_number`, then `group_by` the `Id` column. In the second `mutate`, we use a `sapply` iteration to find the range of row number of interest and set these rows to 1 in the new `Block` column.

```r
library(tidyverse)

n = 2
m = 3

df %>% 
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
  group_by(Id) %>% 
  mutate(rn = row_number(), 
         Block = ifelse(rn %in% 
                          c(sapply(1:length(which(df$Interesting == 1)), \(x) 
                                   (which(df$Interesting == 1) - n)[x]:(which(df$Interesting == 1) + m)[x])), 
                        1, 
                        0)) %>% 
  select(-rn)

# A tibble: 8 × 5
# Groups:   Id [1]
     Id  Time Value Interesting Block
  <int> <int> <int>       <int> <dbl>
1     1     0    12           0     0
2     1     1    14           0     1
3     1     2    11           0     1
4     1     3    12           1     1
5     1     4    13           0     1
6     1     5    14           0     1
7     1     6    12           0     1
8     1     7    12           0     0
```